# Sum of fields using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-ce

Some background before asking my question.

Im using sql compact, and i have two tables, 
The first table (IssueEmp)

[image]

The second table (RecEmp)

[image]

```
 SqlCeDataAdapter adap = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM RecEmp", cn);
            DataTable dat = new DataTable();
            DataSet receice = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(receice);
            adap.Fill(dat);

 SqlCeDataAdapter adap1 = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM IssueEmp", cn);
            DataTable dat1 = new DataTable();
            DataSet issue = new DataSet();
            adap1.Fill(issue);
            adap1.Fill(dat1);
```

Im performing a join between RecEmp and IssueEmp using linq

```
var res = from t1 in receice.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()

                      join t2 in issue.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()                                            
                         on new 
                         {
                             CNo = t1.Field<int>("CNo"),
                             Empid = t1.Field<int>("EmpID") 
                         } 
                         equals new 
                         {
                             CNo = t2.Field<int>("CNo"),
                             Empid = t2.Field<int>("EmpID") 
                         }                     
                      select new
                       {
                           SNo = t1.Field<int>("SNo"),
                           ChNo = t1.Field<int>("CNo"),
                           EmpID = t1.Field<int>("EmpID"),
                           DateIssued = t2.Field<DateTime>("Date"),                                                                               
                           RMIssued = t2.Field<string>("RMCode"),
                           QuantityIssued = t2.Field<double>("Quantity"),

                           DateReceived = t1.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
                           RMCodeReceived = t1.Field<string>("RMCode"),
                           QuantityReceived = t1.Field<double>("Quantity")

                       };
```

The output Im getting from the above linq query is

[image]

But I don't know how to get the sum of issued quantity likewise the sum of received quantity, lastly the difference between the two sum as the diff. The required is below.

[image]

Comment: See [HOW TO: Implement a DataSet JOIN helper class in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326080/en-us)

Comment: @A.V why should i use DataSet JOIN helper class when it can be done with linq...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**

I´m a bit lazy so I didn´t use all the records you provided, only the first four records.

**Expected result:**

This is what I got:

[image]

**The Linq query:**

```
var query = from d in data
           group d by new { d.DateIssued, d.EmpId, d.ChNo, d.DateReceived }
           into x
           select new {
                Date = x.Key.DateIssued,
                CNo = x.Key.ChNo,
                EmpId=x.Key.EmpId,
                CRi = x.Where(c=>c.RMIssued == "CR").Sum(c=>c.QuantityIssued),
                SJi = x.Where(c=>c.RMIssued == "SJ").Sum(c=>c.QuantityIssued),
                TTi = x.Where(c=>c.RMIssued == "TT").Sum(c=>c.QuantityIssued),
                WRi = x.Where(c=>c.RMIssued == "WR").Sum(c=>c.QuantityIssued),
                TotalIssued = x.Sum(c => c.QuantityIssued),

                DateReceived = x.Key.DateReceived,
                CRr = x.Where(c=>c.RMCodeReceived == "CR").Sum(c=>c.QuantityReceived),
                SJr = x.Where(c=>c.RMCodeReceived == "SJ").Sum(c=>c.QuantityReceived),
                TTr = x.Where(c=>c.RMCodeReceived == "TT").Sum(c=>c.QuantityReceived),
                WRr = x.Where(c=>c.RMCodeReceived == "WR").Sum(c=>c.QuantityReceived),
                TotalReceived = x.Sum(c => c.QuantityReceived),

                Diff = x.Sum(c => c.QuantityIssued) - x.Sum(c => c.QuantityReceived)
            };
```

**Data used:**

And this is the set of data I used to test it:

```
var data= new []{
    new { SNo= 9,  ChNo=5,  EmpId=81, DateIssued=dateIssued, RMIssued="SJ", QuantityIssued=30,   DateReceived=dateReceived, RMCodeReceived="SJ", QuantityReceived=20.3},
    new { SNo= 10, ChNo=5,  EmpId=81, DateIssued=dateIssued, RMIssued="SJ", QuantityIssued=30,   DateReceived=dateReceived, RMCodeReceived="CR", QuantityReceived=9.6},
    new { SNo= 11, ChNo=28, EmpId=82, DateIssued=dateIssued, RMIssued="TT", QuantityIssued=30.5, DateReceived=dateReceived, RMCodeReceived="TT", QuantityReceived=29},
    new { SNo= 12, ChNo=28, EmpId=82, DateIssued=dateIssued, RMIssued="WR", QuantityIssued=10,   DateReceived=dateReceived, RMCodeReceived="TT", QuantityReceived=29}
};
```

I recommed you use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to test it.

Good luck!